# setup for multiple swagger API files

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am working on a project where we rewrite the interfacing of an existing application, porting everything to swagger/openAPI.

Right now, each feature has its own yml file right now, which is a standalone spec. But there are some drawbacks:

- duplicated content in the yml files (e.g. models which could be shared accross files)
- duplicated program code (which is generated from those yml files).
- having to process each yml file individually when using tools.

Ideally we would like to have a seperate **folder for each service**, with the models and service description for that specific service close together, but separated from the other services. Of course there are also shared models, which we then want in a different folder (e.g. "/shared-models"). And finally we want all those files to be included by **1 main yml root file**.

So, we have been looking at splitting/importing files with a `$ref` attribute. But it is tricky to come up with **a full-scale file and folder structure**, because the spec seems to allow usage of `$ref` on some places, but not all places. You can't just split and structure files any way you like. So, we will probably need some kind of trade-off.

I was especially wondering how other companies do this setup. (e.g. an **example** of a setup that uses an enterprise level structure of swagger files, would be excellent.) We like to keep things simple and whenever possible according to standards or popular **conventions**.

*(For clarity: my question is not: "how to use $ref")*